# Unable to drop my dragged item anywhere i desire using drag and drop in telerik treeview

Tags: wpf, telerik, treeview

I am having two trees created using drag and drop ,Telerik treeview,one for input and other for output,with many nodes.

When i drag any of input to drop in outputs, it shows my restricted sign to drop & drop is disable (normally on already present nodes of output) but when i move it a little down then it allows me to drop there. Not able to figure out how to enable drop anywhere in output panel.

Comment: I guess it would help if you publish your drag and drop code…

Comment: Actualy I am just new to this platform, I didnt do anything actually in code so no idea of code.Just given work to fix this bug out of project.

Comment: I joined StackOverflow just a few months ago and this is the perfect place to get an answer to your problem. But with the information you provided so far nobody will be able to help you to fix that problem. Maybe have a look at this example: http://wpftutorial.net/DragAndDrop.html and you will see some sample code. Something similar should be in your project.